# Is there any agreement that allows China to use Russian naval bases for its military cooperation?

Tags: russian-federation, china, military, geopolitics

> Over the past decade, China and Russia have transformed Europe’s
> maritime security seascape through their military basing access and
> port investments across maritime Europe — from the Baltic and Black
> Seas to the Mediterranean. Europe and NATO have made some progress
> toward addressing many of these challenges, but they must continue to
> dedicate resources and platforms to ensure the long-term security of
> their many maritime geoeconomic assets.

https://www.brookings.edu/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/FP_20230207_europe_basing_gresh.pdf

This report discuss how China and Russia is shaping the maritime security in Europe, but the report mention both countries as separate entities doing their own things, so it seemed to assume that there was no agreement between the two countries that would allow Chinese military vessels to use Russian ports. Is there any such agreement in place as of now, and were there any discussion of implementing such an arrangement in the future?

Comment: I think no. IIRC Mao was incredibly paranoid about that. And that probably set some tradition.  They do some maneuvers together.